# Set default value of dropdown in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have an array like [ {code: 'in', name: 'India' }, ...] for all countries and rendered a dropdown list with all countries as `option` using `map`. I want to set India as default value when the component renders but I always get Argentina as default option because it is first on the array.
Please suggest me a way to achieve it. I tried finding answers but those are not working or may be I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code required :

```
export default function NavBar({ setUserSearch, country, setCountry }) {

    const handleCountryChange = (e) => {
        setCountry({code: e.target.value, name: e.target.innerText})
    }

    return (
        <select className="country_dropdown mx-3 py-1 px-1 text-dark" onChange = {handleCountryChange}> 
            {countries.map(country => {
                 return <option value = {country.code} key = {country.code}>{country.name} 
                        </option>
                       }
                  )
             }
        </select>
           ) 
}
```

Comment: Where are you binding `value` attribute of `select`?

Comment: I am giving the value attribute a state "country" which by default is "India" and changing its state using the callback function "handleCountryChange" on "onChange" event listener whenever any other option is selected

Comment: I mean on the actual select. As in to bind the value of this form element to a particular state property. React can then effectively using the values specified on the option elements to determine if it’s selected automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`option` has an attribute called "selected", which is a boolean setting.
So you can do this -

```js
<select className="country_dropdown mx-3 py-1 px-1 text-dark" onChange = {handleClick}> 
   {countries.map(country => {
      return <option value={country.code} key={country.code} selected={country.code === 'in'}>
                {country.name}
             </option>
   })}
</select>
```

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Beat me to the answer, but here is a demo showing how this should work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-43uxrt?file=src%2FNavbar.jsx

Comment: Apologies, nice work though!

Comment: Ya, it worked! I also tried using this way selected={country.code === 'in' ? true : false} but this gave me a warning as "Use value or default value props instead of select on option". Could you tell me please why is it different from your answer?