# How to pre-populate dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm not familiar with react; how do I pre-populate the dropdown on page load with -- None -- which is one of the selected options? The value for -- None -- is "English"

```
<TextField
  placeholder="select language"
  variant="outlined"
  label="select your preferred language"
  select
  id="outlined-error"
  fullWidth
  onChange={(e) => {
    formValues.languageSelect.value = e.target.value
  }}
  inputProps={{
    style: {
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: '4px',
      padding: '10px',
    }
  }}
>
  {languagesList.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

I tried defaultValue but can't get it to prop the change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427830/set-default-value-of-dropdown-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you define your state but you should add a `value` prop to the TextField so that the select becomes controlled. Then, just set the default value of `formValues.languageSelect` to `English` and the select will have that option selected by default.

```
<TextField
  placeholder="select language"
  variant="outlined"
  label="select your preferred language"
  select
  id="outlined-error"
  fullWidth
  value={formValues.languageSelect.value}
  onChange={(e) => { formValues.languageSelect.value = e.target.value }}
  inputProps={{
    style: {
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: '4px',
      padding: '10px',
    }
  }}
>
  {languagesList.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

Comment: It didn't pre-select it. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: Where are you getting `TextField` from? Is that a custom component? It could be helpful if you shared all of the relevant code for `TextField` as well as the parent that contains it

Comment: TextField is coming from a different app part, which I can't access. This is all I see on the final page. Every form element here uses TextField, which I assume is a custom component.